# Use Allure report V2 via pytest on Python3

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I am trying to use Allure report with Python3, although the libraries used for Python Pytest are not supported, from what I can see.

The documentation say that Allure plugin for pytest support the previous version of allure only.

Is there a workaround to use pytest on python3, and get the Allure reports created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

First of all, you need to remove ALL the old libraries and packages, since it may cause problems.

Then you need to install the Allure command line via `Brew`.

That will allow you to generate reports from the output of your tests.
Then what is left is to install via `Pip` the package for Python, which is called `Allure-pytest`.

I did notice that some imports are different from the previous version of Allure; not sure what is the problem though, since importing Allure works fine in Python, but when I generate reports, I get errors because `Objevt of type bytearray is not JSON serializable`. 
Was working with the previous version of Allure API on Python 2.7, so I am not sure what is wrong, but most likely it is user error.